# Why was earth created?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 1:1 `In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.`

1. Why was earth created?
   Isaiah 45:18 `For thus saith the Lord that created the heavens; God himself that formed the earth and made it; he hath established it, he created it not in vain,`  **`he formed it to be inhabited:`**`I am the Lord; and there is none else.`
2. How was earth created? (<strike>Is it related to Big Bang Theory?</strike>)

Comment: Welcome to BH community where we can all learn together  more about the ultimate truth - the Sovereign God and His creation , and who we are and our destinies as His creation  living in His world of  creation. I suggest you first to read the Bible. With your background, I am sure you will be able to find answeres to your questions in the Scripture, if you read it with mind of open and  heart of hunger for the truth.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  There are too many questions here at once - are you able to break this down into smaller pieces to answer seperately?

Comment: thanks Dottard for answering 1. he formed it to be inhabited: I am the Lord; and there is none else.

Comment: Hi Merrin - great to see you refining your question. If you can get it to align with the site scope, it will be reopened. Currently it's still valid for closure for a few different reasons - lots of questions, not all of them aligned with examining the texts themselves. I'd suggest having a read through the pinned article '[On Topic](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' before you break it up, and have a think on which of these questions are really about the text.

Comment: Thanks Steve Taylor for your suggession.

Comment: *Why* questions are tricky when a passage doesn't give a clear answer. I think that's the case here - Genesis 1 describes *what* he did, but not necessarily *why*. We don't allow verse search questions here. Instead I think your best option would be to ask on the [Christianity.se] site for a particular denomination's answer to the question of why God made the universe.

Comment: Thanks, curiousdannii